# Why some library like Vuetify suggest installing font via CDN in production?

Tags: vuetify.js, cdn, jsdelivr

[image]

Please see the screenshot or [vuetify's docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#font-installation)

Vuetify suggests installing their dependency Font via `jsdelivr`.

This makes me very confused, I didn't pay anything to `jsdelivr`, and I can just use this to my production website?

What if my website has massive traffic?

Wouldn't like cost `jsdelivr` so much money?

```html
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
```